# Why in my local repository I see commits of other developers?

Tags: git

Before a push I wanted to check what exactly am I going to push. For that I have executed:

```
git cherry -v
```

And I got a list of commits with commits messages. However, some messages I could not recognize as mine. Then I use

```
git show {SHA-1}
```

And I saw that the author of commit is not me but another developer. I am surprised by that because I have expected that on my local repository I have only mine commits. How these other commits could come ot my repository?

Comment: Have you pulled and merged in the past?

Comment: According to your questions of the past couple of days you should really benefit from reading a Git tutorial or two. If you see other people's commits, you have fetched data from a remote, or you have shared your index and they committed on that. Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git is a *distributed* source control system.  Every clone of a repo is a *complete copy of the repo*, allowing you to perform nearly all source control operations without the need to connect to a central server.  (The only time you do have to connect is, of course, to share changes.  And even that can be done by "sneaker-net" methods using bundle files, if the need arises.)

So when you clone a repo, you get everybody's commits.  When you fetch (or pull) you get everybody's commits and those are added to your local repo.  This is necessary; for example, how else would you integrate your changes with those of other developers (while preserving the ability to work in a distributed workflow)?

If you want to isolate your changes from those of other developers, that's a matter of branching strategy.